# How do I change what is inside d3.selectAll() with a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart where I make each bar of a separate class *"bar"+number*:

```
chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar" + chart_x(d.year); })
```

If `chart_x(d.year)` is `5`, then it gives out a `rect` bar with class `bar5`. All works well so far.

Now I need to access each bar with `d3.selectAll()` in order to change the style of each bar. Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
d3.selectAll(function (d) {return ".bar" + chart2_x(d.year); }).style("stroke", "red");
```

What I need it to do, for example, if the class is `".bar5"`, is `d3.selectAll(".bar5").style("stroke", "red");` but with `5` being variable.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do what you want:

You can use `filter()` function. However, in that case you will need to make sure that you do not use a suffix in class name. So, assuming that you only use `bar` as the class, you can do something like this:

```
var yearToBeSelected = 5;
d3.selectAll(".bar")
.filter(function (d) {
   return chart2_x(d.year) == yearToBeSelected;
})
.style("stroke", "red");
```

If however, it is a requirement that class names are of the format `bar<number>`, you can use regex in select all selector like this

```
var yearToBeSelected = 5;

//selects all elements with class starting with bar
d3.selectAll("*[class^=bar]") 
.filter(function (d) {
   return chart2_x(d.year) == yearToBeSelected;
})
.style("stroke", "red");
```